# Fixed Psionic Combat

Tags: dnd-3e, psionics, homebrew

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25315/was-psionic-combat-removed-from-pathfinder) (especially KRyan's answer) made me remember what Psionic Combat was. In my 3.0 group we never encountered psionicenemies so we didn't realize how bad it was. On paper, it looked good but I can see why it is not. It burns mana and it damages mana.
Is there any widely known and accepted fix to Psionic Combat?

Comment: There was a fix, of sorts, in the *Expanded Psionics Handbook*: converting the attack and defense modes into standard powers. You can also look at the AD&D 2nd Edition book *The Will and the Way* (WotC posted it free online at some point) to see the original implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3.5 third-party book *Hyperconscious* is generally **very** well-received by Psionics fans, and does offer a version of Psionic Combat for 3.5. But I think it’s optional and it’s not the part of the book that I hear people rave about, so I’m not sure how good it actually is. Better than the 3.0 version, at the very least, it seems.

As my answer probably makes clear, I have not personally read *Hyperconscious*. I know that Dreamscarred Press, which sort of expands upon *Hyperconscious*, never recreated Psionic Combat. [This thread](http://www.dreamscarredpress.com/dragonfly/ForumsPro/viewtopic/t=1703.html) indicates that at least one person at Dreamscarred Press considered Psionic Combat to be an unnecessary complication that he wasn’t particularly interested in expanding or recreating.

Answer (score 1):

**Not to my Knowledge**

On four different RPG communities the only comment I've ever heard on psionic combat is "Thank the black gods of Hell that it's gone." As far as I'm aware no credible fix  has ever been published.