# Can a tiefling use its darkness ability on itself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth, tiefling

Is it technically possible for a tiefling to use its *darkness* to affect a large object such as himself? If yes, could this be treated as a stealth bonus *in the dark*? My level 7 tiefling Dex-based stealth fighter would find this really useful.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I've edited your question so it sounds less like a poll, which the site frowns upon. Questions are usually answered from the rules first unless you're actually looking for house rules. It also sounds like you're new to *Pathfinder* (or, at least, its spells)--stay strong! Keep in mind that spells, despite their complexity, unless the GM says otherwise will usually *only* do what they say they do (with sometimes hilarious consequences). The site is happy to help with attempts at interpreting them, however. Thank you for your participation, and have fun.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the rule-based answer. May I ask why all the edits? Is it a length issue?

Comment: It's a clarity issue. While extra information *necessary* for answering the question is encouraged (for example, character optimization questions require *a lot* of information), unless the other information is necessary or requested by comments for clarification, other information tends to distract from the question, with folks sometimes answering parts of the question you didn't need or want answered! You *can* include other information (like I did [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73159/8610)), but, for example, I didn't want the poll-type ending of your original to attract downvotes.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to wait, like, a day before accepting an answer. Accepting an answer too early discourages others from posting their own competing answers that could have been more useful than the first one.

Comment: I see. It's just that I found this answer really fulfilling and didn't think about the community's possible need for a different kind of reply. Thanks again! Will be aware from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Most GMs will probably rule that the tiefling can't target its own body with its *darkness*

According to rules, the typical [tiefling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tiefling)'s spell-like ability *darkness* works just like the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*darkness*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness), and that spell has as its [target object touched](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell). As the typical tiefling isn't usually an *object* but a *creature*, it would take a liberal GM to allow the tiefling to slap the *darkness* effect directly on itself rather than than, for example, a weapon it's wielding or its armor. However, once the *darkness* effect's in place, it may be possible for the tiefling to hide within the area.

You can learn more about light levels (which are fairly complicated and resist a simple summary) [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/vision-and-light). The area's light level must be at least dim (i.e. granting a 20% miss chance due to concealment) for the typical creature to make [Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth) skill checks to hide within. The tiefling spell-like ability *darkness* reduces the light level in the affected area by one step.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the answer I was looking for. Lots of reading ahead!

Comment: Could a tiefling cast darkness on an object he's wearing or carrying - for example, his sweatband, thereby creating a mobile darkness effect that moves around with him and hides his terrible fashion sense?

Comment: @GMJoe Already mentioned ("[I]t would take a liberal GM to allow the tiefling to slap the darkness effect directly on itself rather than than, for example, a weapon it's wielding or its armor"), but should I make it clearer that after i'ts used the effect moves with the tiefling? (I thought that was clear, but I'll edit if it's not.)

Comment: Lessening one's visibility by using darkness on equipment seems legit to me.

Comment: @AlexAgapov O, it totally is! (The only difficulty is that normally the game's played top-down, so on a large enough playing surface, a *player* can metagame to determine the *darkness* effect's center (even if the character couldn't) and launch attacks at that center space and, likewise, the tiefling; of course, as the tiefling could use the spell-like ability on an object then drop the object yet remain hidden in the area, that's not really that big of a deal.)